# Usar foreach para mostrar datos de arrays dentro de un array

Tags: php, array, joomla3

Estoy usando los componentes CCv5 y CFv5 (de chronoengine) dentro de la última versión de Joomla 3.x para, en primer lugar, obtener información de diferentes tablas y ahora lo que necesito es mostrar parte de la información con un foreach (o similar).

En concreto, estos son los arrays que tengo y quiero mostrar toda la información del array de nombre Data12:

```
Array
(
    [cont] => lists
    [ccname] => monlistado
    [act] => edit
    [gcb] => 1
    [CCT] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [uniq_id] => 726a43b057c4efa01756d64336e0c037f9e4eb78
            [user_id] => 660
            [created] => 2017-09-30 18:00:38
            [modified] => 2017-10-01 16:42:15
            [modified_userid] => 661
            [s01p04id_investigador] => investigador
            [s01p04monitor] => 661
            [s01p04id_paciente] => in31ve3691
            [s01p01notasdeseccion] => Notas de ejemplo de la sección
            [s01p01tipopaciente] => 1
            [s01p01fecha_de_nacimiento] => 09-05-2007
            [s01p01fecha_de_ingreso] => 13-09-2017
            [s01p01s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_ninv] => esta es una nota
            [s01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_nmon] => 
            [s01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_q] => 0
            [s01p01edad] => 10
            [s01p01peso] => 80
            [s01p01talla] => 180
            [s01p01imc] => 24.69
        )

    [Data12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2017-09-30 18:00:39
                    [s01p04monitor] => 661
                    [s01p01s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_ninv] => notas
                    [s01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_nmon] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2017-09-30 18:01:52
                    [s01p04monitor] => 661
                    [s01p01s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_ninv] => 
                    [s01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_nmon] => notas
                )

        )

)
```

¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: ¿cómo quieres mostrar dicha información?

Comment: Cierto, perdonad.

En concreto, necesito unicamente mostrar, por cada array, el campo 'created', el campo 's01p01s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_ninv' y el campo 's01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_nmon'.

Es decir, recorrer el primer array, mostrar los tres campos, y luego saltar al siguiente array y volver a mostrar esos tres, y así sucesivamente.

Me da igual si es en una tabla o simplemente cada campo dentro de un <span>

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que el OP explica en los comentarios, se podría hacer con un foreach (asumiendo que el arreglo se llame $myArray):

```
foreach ($myArray['Data12'] as $data) {

    echo $data['created'] . '<br>';

    echo $data['s01p01s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_ninv'] . '<br>';

    echo $data['s01p02s01p01fecha_de_ingreso_nmon'] . '<br>';

}
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, en cuanto a la parte de html, puedes manejar las etiquetas que desees o crear una tabla, etc.

Comment: No funciona. No me muestra nada.

Puedo mostrarte el formulario online:
Accede a esta URL: http://update.coupeclinicaltrial.com/monitores/pacientes-asignados?cont=lists&ccname=monlistado&act=edit&gcb=1

El código PHP que has indicado lo inserto en diferentes zonas del formulario y no muestra nada (ahora mismo está insertado justo antes del marco azul (entre fecha de nacimiento y fecha de ingreso)

Comment: puedes poner parte del codigo donde estas incluyendo la solucion de Shaz? creo que es correcta, mas bien parece cosa de que no este implementado correctamente en tu codigo...